# AWS EMR history server - ERROR 500 for large job

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I'm using AWS EMR v6.7.0.

I can view the history server UI after the cluster has already terminated. However, when I try to go to large jobs, I get the following exception (for smaller jobs, everything seems fine)

Any idea on what can be done?

```
HTTP ERROR 500 org.sparkproject.guava.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
URI:    /history/application_1684756326664_0001/1/jobs/
STATUS: 500
MESSAGE:    org.sparkproject.guava.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
SERVLET:    org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer$$anon$1-257cc1fc
CAUSED BY:  org.sparkproject.guava.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
CAUSED BY:  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Caused by:
org.sparkproject.guava.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2261)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4004)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4874)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.ApplicationCache.get(ApplicationCache.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.ApplicationCache.withSparkUI(ApplicationCache.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer.org$apache$spark$deploy$history$HistoryServer$$loadAppUi(HistoryServer.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer$$anon$1.doGet(HistoryServer.scala:104)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:503)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.HttpSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpSecurityFilter.scala:95)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:763)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:234)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.ProxyRedirectHandler.handle(JettyUtils.scala:581)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:386)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    at org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:412)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer.contentsAsString(TextBuffer.java:465)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.getText(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:301)
    at org.json4s.jackson.JValueDeserializer._deserialize$1(JValueDeserializer.scala:26)
    at org.json4s.jackson.JValueDeserializer._deserialize$1(JValueDeserializer.scala:48)
    at org.json4s.jackson.JValueDeserializer.deserialize(JValueDeserializer.scala:57)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:322)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:2033)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1491)
    at org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.parse(JsonMethods.scala:33)
    at org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.parse$(JsonMethods.scala:20)
    at org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.parse(JsonMethods.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ReplayListenerBus.replay(ReplayListenerBus.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ReplayListenerBus.replay(ReplayListenerBus.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.$anonfun$parseAppEventLogs$3(FsHistoryProvider.scala:1125)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.$anonfun$parseAppEventLogs$3$adapted(FsHistoryProvider.scala:1123)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider$$Lambda$357/662521400.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2787)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.$anonfun$parseAppEventLogs$1(FsHistoryProvider.scala:1123)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.$anonfun$parseAppEventLogs$1$adapted(FsHistoryProvider.scala:1121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider$$Lambda$355/23624402.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.parseAppEventLogs(FsHistoryProvider.scala:1121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.rebuildAppStore(FsHistoryProvider.scala:1102)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.createInMemoryStore(FsHistoryProvider.scala:1340)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.getAppUI(FsHistoryProvider.scala:372)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer.getAppUI(HistoryServer.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.ApplicationCache.$anonfun$loadApplicationEntry$2(ApplicationCache.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.ApplicationCache$$Lambda$678/669095258.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.ApplicationCache.time(ApplicationCache.scala:135)
Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.43.v20210629
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the logs of your jobs are bigger than the heap of your history-server process can handle.

I suppose that you're doing something similar to this to start up your history server:

```bash
cd $SPARK_HOME/sbin
./start-history-server.sh
```

To successfully start up your history server with enough heap space, edit the file located at `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh` (if you're not already using this file, there should be a template file called `spark-env.sh.template` which you can simply rename to `spark-env.sh`) and add something like the following line to that file:

```
SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY=2g
```

This will start up your history server process with a heap space of 2g.

The value that you need to choose here is of course dependent on the size of your log files (you can check this out by looking at the files in your `spark.eventLog.dir`) but I chose `2g` here for the example since it's simply twice the size of the default.